# Checkboxes within the span, select deselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following html generated through my PHP code.
What I want to do is that when I select the checkbox in span "row" then the checkboxes   for "main_row" span in which "row" is contained in,
should be checked automatically.
Also when I deselect the "main_row" checkbox, then all the contained in "row: checkboxes"   should be deselected.
I can use JavaScript or jQuery for this purpose.

```
<span id="mainTopHeading" >Imports &amp; Exports</span>
<span id="lblmainTopHeading">Categories</span>
<span id="main_row" class="mystyleClass" >
    <input type="checkbox" id="pH" curstomerName="Zubair & CO" recordID="1920"  />
    <span title="Zubair & CO"  id="pHName">Zubair &amp; CO</span>
    <span title="Roland">Roland</span>
</span>
<span id="row"  recordID="1920"  curstomerName="Zubair & CO"   >
    <input type="checkbox"  recordID="1920" curstomerName="Zubair & CO"  />
    <span>Order  Rice &amp; Sugar</span>
    <span>Roland</span>
</span>

<span id="mainTopHeading" >Manufacturing</span>
<span id="lblmainTopHeading">Categories</span>

<span id="main_row" class="mystyleClass" >
    <input type="checkbox" id="pH" curstomerName="Howard Manufacturing" recordID="1870"  />
    <span title="Howard Manufacturing"  id="pHName">Howard Manufacturing</span>
    <span title="Roland"> Roland</span>
</span>
<span id="row" index="1" recordID="1870"  curstomerName="Howard Manufacturing"  >
    <input type="checkbox" style="left:10;" recordID="1870"  curstomerName="Howard Manufacturing" />
    <span>Order Tires and Plastic products</span>
    <span>Roland</span>
</span>
<span id="row" index="1" recordID="1870"  curstomerName="Howard Manufacturing"  >
    <input type="checkbox" style="left:10;" recordID="1870"  curstomerName="Howard Manufacturing" />
    <span>Order Electronics</span>
    <span>Roland</span>
</span>

<span id="main_row" class="mystyleClass"  >
    <input type="checkbox" id="pH" curstomerName="James & Sons" recordID="1866"  />
    <span title="James & Sons"  id="pHName">James &amp; Sons</span>
    <span title="Roland">Roland</span>
</span>
<span id="main_row" class="mystyleClass"  >
    <input type="checkbox" id="pH" curstomerName="Villa Thresa Inc" recordID="1866"  />
    <span title="Villa Thresa Inc"  id="pHName">Villa Thresa Inc</span>
    <span title="Roland">Roland</span>
</span>
<span id="main_row" class="mystyleClass"  >
    <input type="checkbox" id="pH" curstomerName="Bangkok Manufacturing" recordID="1866"  />
    <span title="Bangkok Manufacturing"  id="pHName">Bangkok Manufacturing</span>
    <span title="Roland">Roland</span>
</span>

<span id="row"  recordID="1920"  curstomerName="Zubair & CO"   >
    <input type="checkbox"  recordID="1920" curstomerName="Zubair & CO"  />
    <span>Order  Rice &amp; Sugar</span>
    <span>Roland</span>
</span>

<span id="mainTopHeading">Misc.</span>
<span id="lblmainTopHeading">Different things</span>
<span id="main_row" class="mystyleClass"  >
    <input type="checkbox" id="pH" curstomerName="Bangkok Manufacturing" recordID="1866"  />
    <span title="Bangkok Manufacturing"  id="pHName">Bangkok Manufacturing</span>
    <span title="Roland">Roland</span>
</span>​
```

Comment: You have several elements with the same ID, `main_row` and `row` for example. This is invalid since IDs must be unique and not reused on the same page. It will likely cause problems.

Comment: Also, your `<span>` elements with the `row` ID (which should be a class) don't appear to be contained within a `main_row` as your question seems to suggest.

Comment: well they are geenrated through php, so there could be several instances. I can add a class="main_row" and a class="row". and if I do that how can we solve it then? thanks

Comment: You're going to run into all kinds of problems with your markup the way it is.  If you want a hierarchical relationship, your markup elements should be laid out in that fashion, otherwise, you are creating unnecessary headache for yourself.  If you nested your row spans inside of the main_row spans then there's a really simple answer to your question.  Also, if you can change / add a class to the elements, you should be able to change the id right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you make the `id` to `class` change @patrick suggests above, you can do this:

```
$(".main_row :checkbox").change(function() {
  $(this).closest(".main_row").nextUntil(".main_row")
         .find(":checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
});
```

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rzwzF/), when you check/uncheck the checkbox in the `.main_row`, it goes up to the `.main_row` it's in, uses [`.nextUntil(".main_row")`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to get all the `<span>` elements between the clicked `.main_row` and the next, so this category.  Then it gets any checkboxes in there and sets their `checked` property to the same as the checkbox in the `.main_row` you clicked on.

If there may be something besides `.row` in there, you can add a [`.filter(".row")`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) after the [`.nextuntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to restrict it to `.row` elements.

Comment: I think OP wanted the trigger to be on the `checkbox` under `.row`: *' when I select the checkbox in span "row"'*. So you'd need to backtrack to `.main_row` first. I still think the question implies nesting that doesn't exist. Your example really messed with my head until I looked at the CSS and realized you used `nextUntil()`. :o)

Comment: Hi Nick Craver  Thanks for that however, its working opposite. What I wanted was when I check the sub checkbox, then it should check the main check box and it there are no sub checkboxes checked, then the main checkbox should not be checked. Can you tell me how. Thanks again

Comment: @user295189 - Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/rzwzF/2/ Still trying to grasp exactly what you're after :)

Comment: Nick Craver, yes almost! only thing is that its not letting me select if there are no sub-checkboxes. I still want to be able to select if there are no sub checkboxes. Thanks a millions

Comment: @user295189 - In that case just remove the very first like that sets those to `disabled`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rzwzF/3/

Comment: @Nick Craver - if I do that then it will be a bug as the users can uncheck the top level but not the sub one, which is a problem. so if they unselect the top one can we unselect all the bottom ones too?
thanks

Comment: @user295189 - Combine the first and third demos, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rzwzF/4/

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that (I think) does what you want.

(Used Nick's example as a starting point. I see that Nick posted a similar solution, but this one takes a different approach. )

In addition to what you requested, if you click the checkbox under `.main_row`, it will check/uncheck all its related `.row` checkboxes.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/nykda/

```
$(".row input").change(function() {
    var $row= $(this).closest(".row");
    var $main_row = $row.prev('.main_row').length ? $row.prev('.main_row') : $row.prevUntil(".main_row").prev();
    $main_row.find(":checkbox").attr("checked", function(i,attr) {
        return $main_row.nextUntil('.main_row').filter(':has(input:checked)').length ? "checked" : false;
    });
});

$(".main_row input").change(function() {
    $(this).closest(".main_row").nextUntil('.main_row').children(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: +1 - Glad you resolved this, I'm knee-deep in figuring out why someone thought we needed `CookieCollection` *and* `CookieContainer` in .Net :-/